# $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)= \text{Does not exist}$

Tags: limits

> let $f$ Periodic function (Except Constant functions) then :
>
> $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)= \text{Does not exist}$

is it right ??

such that :

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \sin x= \text{Does not exist}$$

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \cos x= \text{Does not exist}$$

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \tan x= \text{Does not exist}$$

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \cot x= \text{Does not exist}$$

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \lfloor x\rfloor +\lfloor -x \rfloor= \text{Does not exist}$$

is it right ??

Comment: Constant functions?

Comment: If, however, you consider only periodic functions where a primitive period exists, then the conjecture is correct.

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong. Every constant function is periodic but $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exists. Furthermore it is difficult to consider something like $\lim_{x \to \infty} \tan(x)$.

Comment: It is meaningless, even, to consider the limit of $\tan$ at infinity because for the definition of limit at infinity it is required that an interval $]a,+\infty[$ for some $a$ is contained in the domain of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong.  There does exist a periodic function with a limit:

$$f(x)=c$$

for a constant $c$.  Then the limit is trivial, but without assuming this to be the only case, you will find:

for $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ to exist, and $f(x)=f(x+T)$, then it must be the case that for all $a,b\in[0,T)$, then $f(a)=f(b)$, so it must be a constant function.